# Is it a good practice and are there any visible gains by serving out all static content via WebResource.axd?

Tags: asp.net, .net

We know that it is possible to serve out static content via WebResource.axd, by embedding these static content(images, css, javascript) inside a class library and exposing them via WebResource.axd links. But what visible advantages does it have, or is it disadvantageous when compared to IIS serving these static content directly from Virtual directories?

Answer (score 0):

WebResource.axd exposes resources in assemblies but IIS makes visible files on a file system. It can't be compared as they serve different aims. Some third party companies uses webresource.axd to get their resources packed in assemblies so that the deployment of those assemblies is easy, e.g. DevExpress. Such packaging makes debugging harder though.

Comment: What you have mentioned is correct. But my question is related to faster serving of static content, WebResource.axd vs files served from Virtual directories.